# how to output 2D array to file in python

Tags: arrays

I am very new to Python and trying to learn some basic python tricks for my optical modelling tool. The modelling software I am using has a python wrapper, thus everything has to be done in python.
I am calculating the field value depending on the position of a structure,thus this has to be output to file like a matrix, where rows are the position and columns are field values. I am trying something like this and it looks sort of OK, but when I try to write it to file, it doesn't write it as rows and columns. It should output a 2x2 matrix.
Can someone please help me to sort this out, please feel free to tell me indexing the array is correct too.

Thanks alot

```
    testfile = file("testfile.dat", 'w')
    matrix = [[0 for z in range(2)] for field in range (2)]
    for z in range(2):
      for field in range(2):
       matrix[z][field] = some calculation

    for z in range(2):
      for field in range(2):
       print >> testfile, z, matrix[z][field]

    testfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you want this?

```
for row in matrix:
   for cell in row:
      print >>testfile, cell,
   print >>testfile
```